# Is code reload in Erlang limited to only two version?

Tags: erlang, real-time, upgrade, erlang-otp, on-the-fly

[The ability of Erlang to reload code with ease, without dropping existing connections, is a very attractive proposition, heavily featured as one of the features of the language.](http://youtu.be/rRbY3TMUcgQ?t=7m8s)

What's not explicitly advertised, however, is that, apparently, you can only do such seamless reload a single time, before dropping the existing connections that haven't yet had the chance to switch the execution code path from old to new.

Is it indeed so, or does Erlang/OTP has an extra advanced code reload feature that avoids dropping the executing code paths from the already previous generation, when a second code reload is executed?  ([I mean, nginx, for example, can be binary upgraded any number of times.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#upgrade))

Comment: Yes, just two versions. But you can tell the code loader what version you want, check for non-migrated code, rollback, etc. programatically. You migrate your running processes forward (including whatever sockets they are holding) via [`code_change/3`, appups, relups, etc.](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html#instr) in OTP, or an equivalent function you would need to write yourself otherwise. This takes planning and thought. Erlang is one of the only runtimes that can do this *at all* but it doesn't come for free -- it costs effort on the part of the developer.

Comment: To clarify: in the perfect answer, you'd show the possible workarounds on the issue -- the example of the fact that only two versions run at the same time was already present in the jaerlang2 book from 2013, but nowhere in the book is it discussed how to workaround the issue.

Comment: @zxq9, great comment, you should probably put it as an answer; some possible code references to whether actual Erlang applications go into the trouble of doing that would be good, too.

Answer (score 5):

2 versions only. To illustrate the behavior, I have used the small module:

```
-module (tver).

-compile([export_all]).

start(Name) ->
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE,loop,[]),
    register(Name,Pid).

loop() ->
    receive
        % an internal call won't reload the code. The process keeps
        % executing the current version 
        version -> io:format("version 1~n"), loop();
        % an external call will reload the code. The process will use
        % the new version if any available in the VM. Notes that it
        % will not search in the path if a new version exists!
        update -> io:format("update code~n"), ?MODULE:loop();
        stop -> io:format("bye...~n")
    end.
```

where I change the printed string when I change the version. and now the version management in action:

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
1> c(tver).
{ok,tver}
2> tver:start(v1).
true
3> v1 ! version.
version 1
version
4> whereis(v1).
<0.39.0>
```

modify version to version 2. The c/1 command compiles the code and load it in the VM

```
5> c(tver).        
{ok,tver}
```

Checks that the v1 process is still executing version 1

```
6> v1 ! version.   
version 1
version
7> whereis(v1).    
<0.39.0>
```

But a newly spawned process executes the version 2.

```
8> tver:start(v2). 
true
9> v1 ! version.  
version 1
version
10> v2 ! version.
version 2
version
```

an external call forces to use the new version. In real life, you should make some verifications like what is the old version, what is the new one, is the upgrade possible, is there some data to adapt...

```
11> v1 ! update. 
update code
update
12> v1 ! version.
version 2
version
13> v2 ! version.
version 2
version
14> whereis(v1).   
<0.39.0>
15> whereis(v2). 
<0.50.0>
```

make version 3, compile and reload

```
16> % modif version.
16> c(tver).        
{ok,tver}
17> whereis(v1).    
<0.39.0>
18> whereis(v2).    
<0.50.0>
19> v1 ! version.   
version 2
version
20> v1 ! version.   
version 2
version
21> v2 ! version.   
version 2
version
22> tver:start(v3). 
true
23> v2 ! version.  
version
version 2
24> v3 ! version.
version 3
version
```

fine version the pocesses 1 and 2 are executing the version 2, and the process 3 the version 3.

Now modify to version 4 without upgrading the processes v1 and v2, compile and load the code.

```
25> c(tver).                                                  
{ok,tver}
26> whereis(v1).                                              
undefined
27> whereis(v2).                                              
undefined
```

The n-2 version doesn't exist anymore! The processes V1 and V2 have died, although they were simply waiting on the receive block. In a real OTP system, their supervisor would have restarted them according to their restart strategy.

```
28> tver:start(v4).                                           
true
29> whereis(v3).                            
<0.69.0>
30> whereis(v4).
<0.80.0>
```

V3 and V4 processes are executing the version 3 and 4 respectively

```
31> v3 ! version.                                             
version
version 3
32> v4 ! version.
version 4
version
33>
```

Comment: I think I was more looking for an answer that would show the possible workarounds on the issue -- the example of the fact that only two versions run at the same time are already present in the jaerlang2 book from 2013, but nowhere in the book is it discussed how to workaround the issue.

Comment: @cnst: the example above shows how you can manage the evolution of code: I am not aware of any possibility to run in one single VM more than 2 versions of one module, but the first part shows (in a simplistic example) how one can upgrade the running code from one version to another. OTP offers specific callback to manage code upgrade or downgrade. IMHO it is already really tricky to make one evolution at a time in a production system, I would refuse any request to do more. I'll add some explanations in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can only have two versions of one module running in one time. But you can write your code in a way which switches code to the new one during serving one connection.

Comment: Do you know how common is it for any such code to be present in the wild?  E.g., does ejabberd or riak, or another popular app of your choice, implement any of this?  Any example of how much extra work would something like this require?

Comment: @cnst: There is support for this in gen_* OTP behaviours. So principally you can do it with easy. But there is little difference. A usual way is to freeze application, upgrade and then continue which makes it more controllable. But all of this can be done in few ms.